# cannot make clipboard js to work with textarea

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, clipboard.js

I want to make clipboard js to work with one of my node.js ejs file, since the actual file is too large, I create this file in which I want to use clipboard js to copy the content of the textarea to clipboard.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>pilcit</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<script>
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copyButton');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    alert(e);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    alert(e);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
         <textarea id="copy" class="form-control mt-5" name="content" rows="4">
              content of text area that is to be copied 
         </textarea>

        <button class="copyButton" id="copyButtonId" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="copy">Copy!</button>       
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot make it work, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this

```
data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copy"
```

here the `copy` should be `#copy` because you are selecting it by id

```js
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copyButton');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    alert(e);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    alert(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>


         <textarea id="copy" class="form-control mt-5" name="content" rows="4">
              content of text area that is to be copied 
         </textarea>

        <button class="copyButton" id="copyButtonId" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copy">Copy!</button>
```

Comment: when I make an HTML file with this code and run on my browser it doesn't work?

Comment: @Adarsh you must doing something wrong, 1st check clipboard permission for your page 2nd check for console errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for achieve this, The `execCommand()` method executes the specified command for the selected part of an editable section.

jQuery

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("textarea").select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

JavaScript

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){
  document.querySelector("textarea").select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
};
```

```html
<textarea>Copy my this ya</textarea>
<br>
<button>Select</button>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work, this is my code now
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript">
     var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');
    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="bar">You can copy me ya !</textarea>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="cut" data-clipboard-target="#bar">Cut</button>
</body>
</html>